# Cannot Decrease Loss via Gradient Descent in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, kaggle

I'm getting started with machine learning and I'm attempting to implement Logistic Regression from scratch on the [Kaggle Titanic dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/overview). The code I've written is from what I've learned in an online course and I'm having trouble implementing gradient descent here. The issue is after calculating the W and B gradients and implement an update in the function called logisitic_regression where W = W - alpha*wgrad and b = b - alpha*bgrad, the loss for some reason won't decrease and the W and b parameters won't update. I can't seem to find the error in my code, can anyone help? Please see the following functions. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

```
#Implement sigmoid action potenial function
def sigmoid(z):
    '''
    Input:
        z: Scalar or arry of dimension n
    Output:
    sgmd: Scalar or array of dimension n

    '''

    sgmd = 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    return sgmd



#Define prediction function
def yPredLogistic(X, w, b=0):
   '''
   Input:
    X: nxd matric
    w: d-dimensional vector
    b: scalar (optional, if not pass on is treated as 0)
   Output:
    prob: n-dimensional vector
   '''
   prob = sigmoid(np.inner(X,w.T) +b)

   return prob


#Define negative loglikelihood as log oss 
def log_loss(X, y, w, b=0):
   '''
   Input:
    X: nxd matrix 
    y: n-dimensional vector with labels (+1 or -1)
    w: d=dimensional vector 
   Output:
    nll: a scalar 
   '''


    nll = -np.sum(np.log(sigmoid(y*(np.inner(w.T,X) +b))))

    return nll

   #define gradient 
def gradient(X, y, w, b):
    '''
    Input:
     X: nxd matrix 
     y: n-dimensional vector with labels +1 or -1
     w: d-dimensional vector 
     b: scalr bias term 
   Output:
     wgrad: d-dimensional vector with gradient 
     bgrad: a scalar with gradient
  '''

    n, d = X.shape 
    #wgrad = np.zeros(d)
    #bgrad = 0.0

    #h = y - yPredLogistic(X,w, b)

    wgrad = -y*(sigmoid(-y*(np.inner(w.T,X) +b)))@X

    #partialx = -y*(sigmoid(-y*(np.inner(w.T,X) +b)))@X
    bgrad = np.sum(-y*(sigmoid(-y*(np.inner(w.T,X) +b))))

    return wgrad, bgrad


 #Implement weight update of gradient descent
def logisitic_regression(X,y, max_iter, alpha):
    '''
    Input:
     X: nxd matrix 
     y: n-dimensional vector with labels +1 or -1
     max_iter: max iterations
    alpha: learning or step rate
   Output: 
     w: d-dimensional vector 
     b: scalr bias term 
    losses: losses
'''
    n, d = X.shape
    w = np.zeros(d)
    b = 0.0
    #losses = np.zeros(max_iter)    
    losses = []
    for step in range(max_iter):


        #Get wgradient and b gradient

        wgrad, bgrad = gradient(X,y, w,b)

        w = w - alpha*wgrad

        #update b
        b = b - alpha*bgrad



        #define losses
        losses.append(log_loss(X,y,w,b))


return w, b, losses
```

Comment: This code seems fine but to get help, you’ll really need to show the gradient code you’re using

Comment: What I do when my own implemented machine learning algorithms don't work as expected is I take small sample of dataset and try to solve it by myself and compare with what the algorithm is performing. You can use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to implement the code for +1,-1 output label whereas titanic dataset has output 0/1 not +/-1, so you gotta change your algorithm and calculate derivative and logloss properly as this is not the log loss formula you use for 0/1 label.

Comment: This was exactly it! Thank you so much!